# iOS User Login Session via Devise but Auth_token not kept

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am building an iphone app with a rails-backed server. I am using the devise gem. I am having trouble with user logins on the client-side (everything works on the web side, and even in the terminal with CURL). 
On Xcode I can create a user and I can login. After logging in

```
(and recieving this in the log: "User logged in!")
```

I am then pushed to the indexViewController- and here I receive an error that the posts don't load. The reason is because on the post_controller.rb I have a

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

preventing the posts from loading. The problem is, that the auth_token which was generated upon a successful login, is not being stored and passed along to the different views. So then, in the log I get:

```
'You need to sign in before continuing.'
```

As if the first part of what I just explained never happened..

In the indexViewController viewDidLoad method I have:

```
if (![[APIClient sharedClient] isAuthorized]) {
        LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];
    }
```

isAuthorized is a BOOL in the APIClient that checks if userID>0

In the user model this is the code that creates a login session

```
+ (void)loginUser:(NSString *)signature
                         email:(NSString *)email
                      password:(NSString *)password
                         block:(void (^)(User *user))block
{
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{ @"user": @{
                                    //      @"signature": signature,
                                          @"email": email,
                                          @"password": password
                                          }
                                  };

    [[APIClient sharedClient] postPath:@"/users/sign_in" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        User *user = [[User alloc] initWithDictionary:responseObject];

        if (block) {
            block(user);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        if (block) {
            block(nil);
        }
    }];
}
```

I am guessing it is here that I am missing some auth_token implementation? Since it is generated automatically by devise- I am not sure how to tell xcode to remember it. The auth_token is a string that has a column in the user table on the db. Should I add auth_token as param to the dictionary that holds the user's email and username? Or how do I get the token to persist?
Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not being intimately familiar with AFNetworking this is a stab in the dark, but presumably you need to set the token for subsequent requests. Assuming APIClient is a wrapper you've added around AFHTTPClient, here's a quick idea of what that might look like after reviewing the code here - [AFHTTPClient](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.h).

```
+ (void)loginUser:(NSString *)signature
                         email:(NSString *)email
                      password:(NSString *)password
                         block:(void (^)(User *user))block {
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{ @"user": @{ @"email": email,
                                              @"password": password } };

    [[APIClient sharedClient] postPath:@"/users/sign_in" 
                            parameters:parameters 
                               success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                   User *user = [[User alloc] initWithDictionary:responseObject];

                                   // retrieve and save auth token
                                   NSString *token = [responseObject objectForKey:@"authToken"];
                                   [[APIClient sharedClient] setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:token];

                                   if (block) {
                                       block(user);
                                   }

                               } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                   NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                   if (block) {
                                       block(nil);
                                   }
                               }];
}
```